# How can I add a copy of the first element of a list to the end when the list contains images in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

First I save images in a list.

```
for f in os.listdir(path)[:nr_train_images]:
ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
    continue
im = imread(os.path.join(path,f)) 
train_images.append(im)
```

Then I want to loop over the images and create a copy of every image and add a square on the copied image. And add the copied image to the end of the list.
It works, but my original image (at the beginning of my list) has also changed? **I want the changes only to apply to my copied image.** How can I do this? (I don't want to deep copy the whole list/array first)

```
for z in range(0, nr_train_images):
face = train_images[z] 
# Add a square on random position on the image
x = random.randint(0, 150)
y = random.randint(0, 175) 
cv2.rectangle(face, (x, y), (x + w_width, y + w_height), (255, 255, 255), -1) # draw rectangle on image
# add image to the end of the list
train_images.append(face)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:
face = train_images[z].copy()